# Updating Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, public-key, software-update

...I am trying to update my Eclipse IDE on a MacBook Pro, however I get the following error message: "Public key not found for 810cecf8ba271008 and Public key not found for 700e4f39bc05364b".Can someone assist/help to go around this error problem?

I've done the routine of quitting and reopening Eclipse without any success. I've tried searching and reading comments from a few forums online but nothing helpful seems to be out there.

Comment: You trying updating which Eclipse IDE package of which version? Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error (do not open it, just select it), hit Cmd+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.

Comment: The following is what the error message says: 

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=_Users_brianbtarimo_eclipse_java-2021-12_Eclipse.app_Contents_Eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).

Comment: The error message is not enough. Please see my previous comment on how to get the information needed to help you.

Comment: Ok, understood. This is what I get after following your instructions:  

eclipse.buildId=4.22.0.I20211124-1800
java.version=17.0.1
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/brianbtarimo/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/brianbtarimo/.eclipse_keyring